# Building register array (C)

Tags: c

For my embedded application in C, I want an array of registers that can be accessed by the host system.  Each register has the following field:

Address (32 bits),
Value (32 bits),
Callback (32 bits)

Now, suppose that I have hundreds of these registers.  What is the most efficient way to point to the right register when the host wants to access one particular register base on its address?  Note that the address values are not continued.

Doing an if/else or switch/case structure is out of a question and parsing register by register is not efficient.

The best way I have found up to now is to define each register like this:

RegStruct * RegisterName = ( (RegStruct*) ADDRESS_OF_REGISTER);

But this way, it implies that the ADDRESS_OF_REGISTER must be a valid address in the memory map and it is not portable between platform.

What I want to do is to let the linker place the register in the memory and to access it by its address that I gave.  Is there a way to do it?

Comment: Use a hashmap?  Or a binary search...

Comment: Build a binary search tree with key-value pairs where the address is the key (i.e. sorted by address).

Comment: You are not being very clear. Do these registers have memory addresses or not?

Comment: What about building arrays of access instructions? Call instruction slot 3 to read register 3, etc.

Comment: Or if this system can handle dynamic code, figure out the register encoding in the instructions and write the instructions you need into a function and call it.

Comment: are these addresses static or dynamic?! if these are static, you could possibly link them into a specific address using a linker script, and declare the fields as `volatile`?

Comment: In fact, I don't mind where they are stored in memory.  I want to access them by giving an "logical" address.

Comment: @ZanLynx, can you provide an example or a link for your suggestion about building arrays of access instructions?  Thanks

Comment: Thanks everyone for your suggestions.  I see now that what I wanted to do is not possible.  My solution, for now, is to create an array of registers.  I use the qsort function to sort the register according to their address and I used bsearch function to find the register.  To improve my solution, I could build a balanced binary search tree.  Thanks again for your support.